# JAWS + IE11 + aria-live message read multiple times

Tags: angularjs, uiaccessibility, jaws-screen-reader

Jaws reading aria-live message multiple times.

We are using angularjs. Html code as below,

```
<div role="alert" aria-live="polite">
    <p class="scan-complete-text-auto">{{model.txtErrorMessage}}</p>
</div>
```

Once error message on screen it started reading however it reads three times. This behavior we observed in IE11 with chrome and FF its working fine.

What we are missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing role="alert".
aria-live should be fine.
If JAWS not reading correctly with aria-live, try hiding (display:none) the div tag, update / change the text and then show (display:block).

Comment: Also in anguar the way we render messages on UI matters a lot for narrator sometimes.
we need to use ng-bind="model.txtErrorMessage" instead of {{model.txtErrorMessage}}